# Method containing "yield return" never gets executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield-return

I have just written the following function.

```
private IEnumerator getData()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:3000/data";
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        switch (request.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.LogError("The request has failed: " + request.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                Debug.Log("Here is our data: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It should retrieve a simple string from a backend, but even if I call it it never gets executed.
I first tried to call it in this way:

```
IEnumerator data = getData();
Debug.Log(data);
```

But it didn't work. Then I tried to use a foreach but it didn't work either:

```
IEnumerator data = getData();
foreach(var x in data) {
    Debug.Log(x);
}
```

How can I call this function?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: What is `SendWebRequest()`? What does it return? Why do you consider it's return valid data for `getData` to return?

Comment: From the example in the [unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Get.html) it seems that you must wrap your `getData()` call within a call to `StartCoroutine`.

Comment: @nix86 Did you try to call the function like this: `StartCoroutine(getData());`

Comment: Instead of saying things like "this didn't work", explain what happens when you tried to do it. Otherwise we don't know if it compiles, errors on execution, or gives unwanted behavior, and we don't know how to help you. In this instance you probably got an error which would have helped to narrow the issue greatly: `error CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IEnumerator' because 'IEnumerator' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what's going on? : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html

Answer (score 0):

AztecCodes is right: the `getData` method needs to be called with `StartCoroutine`. Therefore the solution is:

```
StartCoroutine(getData());
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method must return an `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerator`

```
private IEnumerable getData()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:3000/data";
    using (UnityWebRequest request = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
    {
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        switch (request.result)
        {
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.DataProcessingError:
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError:
                Debug.LogError("The request has failed: " + request.error);
                break;
            case UnityWebRequest.Result.Success:
                Debug.Log("Here is our data: " + request.downloadHandler.text);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not so, `IEnumerator` is the correct syntax for a coroutine: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html